# What does it mean, that two questions are linked?

Tags: discussion, questions, linked-questions

Just to feed my curiosity. How can [this one year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10928365/1469208), in which I never took a part (except reading -- no comment, answer, edit, no nothing) can be linked to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928365/how-to-solve-gerrits-your-change-requires-a-recursive-merge-to-resolve) and vice versa?

How can an year old question be linked with a month old question, which doesn't even existed when first was written?

Why these two questions list each other in `Linked` section, while there isn't even a trace of one in another? What does it mean, that two questions are linked and what conditions must be met, to two question become "linked" together.

Comment: Both links are pointing to the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've flagged this as a duplicate, but just to answer your specific case:

> Why these two questions list each other in Linked section, while there isn't even a trace of one in another?

There is a trace. You've linked to that question yourself. Check the second link here, I'm quoting this from your question:

> (especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8737351/1469208) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10928365/1469208)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, especially though this is a duplicate. I wasn't aware, that when question `B` references question `A`, then also `B` appears as linked to `A`. I assumed (incorrectly), that this is always one-way linking, and that only question `A` will be linked to question `B`. Thanks for clarification.